# Crash during installation of flashplugin-installer after upgrade

Tags: installation, aptitude, flash, segmentation-fault

I can't install flashplugin-installer after having upgraded from Maverick to Natty. Something crashes during the installation:

```
$ sudo aptitude install flashplugin-installer
The following NEW packages will be installed:
flashplugin-installer nspluginwrapper{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 185 kB of archives. After unpacking 770 kB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] 
Get:1 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/multiverse nspluginwrapper amd64 1.2.2-0ubuntu9 [175 kB]
Get:2 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/multiverse flashplugin-installer amd64 10.2.159.1ubuntu1 [9.370 B]
Fetched 185 kB in 1s (180 kB/s)           
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously deselected package nspluginwrapper.
(Reading database ... 303033 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking nspluginwrapper (from .../nspluginwrapper_1.2.2-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package flashplugin-installer.
Unpacking flashplugin-installer (from .../flashplugin-installer_10.2.159.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up nspluginwrapper (1.2.2-0ubuntu9) ...
plugin dirs: :/var/lib/flashplugin-installer/
Auto-update plugins from /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
Looking for plugins in /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
Segmentation fault
dpkg: error processing nspluginwrapper (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 139
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of flashplugin-installer:
flashplugin-installer depends on nspluginwrapper (>= 0.9.91.4-2ubuntu1); however:
Package nspluginwrapper is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing flashplugin-installer (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
nspluginwrapper
flashplugin-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up nspluginwrapper (1.2.2-0ubuntu9) ...
plugin dirs: :/var/lib/flashplugin-installer/
Auto-update plugins from /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
Looking for plugins in /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
Segmentation fault
dpkg: error processing nspluginwrapper (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 139
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of flashplugin-installer:
flashplugin-installer depends on nspluginwrapper (>= 0.9.91.4-2ubuntu1); however:
Package nspluginwrapper is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing flashplugin-installer (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
nspluginwrapper
flashplugin-installer
```

Answer (score 4):

This was caused by the `google-talkplugin` package. Uninstalled it and the `flashplugin-installer` worked perfectly. After that I could re-install `google-talkplugin`.

Comment: thx, after removing google-talkplugin, flashplugin-installer could finish --configuring again